# CSS Fixed Position in FireFox without overlapping on body

Tags: html, css, firefox, position, fixed

I am trying to place two DIV containers around my website. I would like these DIV containers to stay in a fixed position at the top of the screen, relative to the container.

My problem is when i apply position:fixed, the banners either disappear, or they don't behave properly when I zoom in on FireFox. Meaning when I zoom in on FireFox the banners will overlap the Container and not stay relative to the container.

I have everything working perfectly here, as far as position and zooming. 
http://kiny.linkedupradio.com/test.html

```
<style>
  body { margin: 0px }

  div#banner1,div#banner2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;  /* DISTANCE FROM TOP OF WINDOW */
   }
  div#banner1 {
    left:-160px;   /* FIXES BANNER TO LEFT SIDE OF WINDOW */
   }
  div#banner2 {
    right:-160px;   /* FIXES BANNER TO RIGHT SIDE OF WINDOW */ 
   }
  .container {
     position:relative;
     width:1000px;
     margin:auto;
  }
</style>

<div id="banner1"><img src="/images/160x600.png"></div>
<div id="banner2"><img src="/images/160x600.png"></div>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspcing="0" border="0" width="990" bgcolor="#999999">
<tr>
   <td height="2000" valign="top" align="center">Website Goes Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm just looking for help on how to make them FIXED to the top of the screen.

Thank you!

Comment: mate - it's just one big grey square here. Try to avoid using tables for layout of your page - use div's instead or html5 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left and right position need to be replaced with margin-left and margin-right for this to work with fixed positioning.

Using your original left: -160px; moved the banner 160px off the screen. Left and Right are relative to the window not the container.

```css
  body { margin: 0px }

  div#banner1,div#banner2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;  /* DISTANCE FROM TOP OF WINDOW */
   }
  div#banner1 {
    margin-left:-160px;   /* you need to position left and right with margins for this to work */
   }
  div#banner2 {
    margin-left: 1000px;  
   }
  .container {
     position:relative;
     width:1000px;
     margin:auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response. I updated the CSS to exactly as you have it - but this pushed my right banner over to the left side.

Here is my Test Page
http://kiny.linkedupradio.com/test.html

Comment: Mmm... .this isn't quite working...

#1 - the Right Banner is over to the Left Side
#2 - when you ZOOM in FireFox, the banners overlap the middle of the site (gray area)

I'm super stuck..

Comment: Sorry should have been `  div#banner2 {
    margin-left:-1000px;  
   }`

Comment: Thanks again - i still don't think its quite right.. zoom part works without over lapping the left side
http://kiny.linkedupradio.com/test.html
I lost the right banner

Comment: Got it!! div#banner2 { margin-left:1000px; }

This works!! I'm brand new to this forum, not sure how to close this out... everything is working now! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Awee... shoot... maybe i spoke too fast...
Everything is working perfect now in the FireFox Browser on a computer... but on my Mobile Android phone, the left banner still overlaps my content area... do you know how to fix this by chance. Thanks again, for your time. kiny.linkedupradio.com/test.html

Comment: you click the tick/check mark next to my answer to close this off :o)

Comment: refresh your browser in your android a few times, it should work fine now.

Comment: It's working great on my Android phone in a Chrome Browser, but it's not behaving correctly on my Android phone in a FireFox Browser. Is there another tag, I should add?

Comment: I don't have experience with firefox on android. If you could mark as correct please and open a new question about fixed positioning on a android phone using firefox. As this current question is more of a general question.